# UnicodeDecodeError reading binary input

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I try to port my code from python 2.7 to 3.4. Under 2.7 it works quite well.
I will import a Picoscope binary file and get the following error under Python 3.4 (ubuntu):

```
in __import_CS
data_A = bin_file_A.read(64)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

here the code piece:

```
bin_file_A = open(infile ,"r")
bin_file_B = open(infile_B ,"r")

######  read file header ########
data_A = bin_file_A.read(64)
data_B = bin_file_B.read(64)

start = 0
stop = struct.calcsize('8d')
n_A = struct.unpack('>8d', data_A[start:stop])
n_B = struct.unpack('>8d', data_B[start:stop])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the files in binary mode:

```
bin_file_A = open(infile_A, "rb")
bin_file_B = open(infile_B, "rb")
```